# PHP: insert text up to delimiter

Tags: php, string, insert

I have a bunch of chat logs that look like this:

```
name: some text
name2: more text
name: text
name3: text
```

I want to highlight the just the names. I wrote some code that should do it, however, I was wondering if there was a much cleaner way than this:

```
$line= "name: text";
$newtext = explode(":", $line,1);
$newertext = "<font color=red>".$newtext[0]."</font>:";
$complete = $newertext.$newtext[1];
echo $complete;
```

Comment: By the way, the <font> tag is deprecated! :) Use <span style="color:red">... Also, remember that attributes must always be quoted! Like <font color="red">.

Comment: @Qualcuno I didn't know that :P <font> is much faster

Comment: Faster to write, you mean? Well, we're in 2011 and the <font> it's not standard. You should avoid it, definitely.

Comment: @Qualcuno or else I would risk future browsers from supporting it?

Comment: I doubt that. But it's still best to use code that respects the standards. It's not that hard, eventually!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks fine, although you can save the temp variables:

```
$newtext = explode(":", $line,1);
echo "<font color=red>$newtext[0]</font>:$newtext[1]";
```

This might be faster or might not, you'd have to test:

```
echo '<font color=red>' . substr_replace($line, '</font>', strpos($line, ':') , 0);
```

Comment: hm I get `Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference`

Comment: @kevin my bad.  I made a mistake with the last param. The problem with the str_replace is that you can't constrain it to to only do one replacement, so this would screw up other occurrences of the ':' used in the conversations.  I updated the str_replace with str_substr() which is an option, but since that would be 2 function calls, i suspect that this could be less efficient than the explode.

Comment: I changed the flow of the program so instead of $line reading line by line, the whole file is read and replaced. These solutions only replace the first line, but were very good for the original question. +1

Answer (score 1):

The answer posted by gview is the simplest it gets, however and just as a reference you can use a regular expression to find the name tag, and replace it with the new html code using preg_replace() as follows:

```
// Regular expression pattern 
$pattern = '/^[a-z0-9]+:?/';

// Array contaning the lines
$str = array('name: some text : Other text and stuff',
        'name2: more text : : TEsting',
        'name: text testing',
        'name3: text Lorem ipsum');

// Looping through the array
foreach($str as $line)
{
    // \\0 references the first pattern match which is "name:" 
    echo preg_replace($pattern, "<font color=red>\\0</font>:", $line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

also try the RegExp like this:

```
$line = "name: text";
$complete = preg_replace('/^(name.*?):/', "<font color=red>$1</font>:", $line);
echo $complete ;
```

**EDIT**

if their names aren't "name" or "name1", just delete the name in pattern, like this

```
$complete = preg_replace('/^(.*?):/', "<font color=red>$1</font>:", $line);
```

Comment: the problem is, I don't know what everyone's names are. Their names aren't "name" or "name1"

Comment: then try this one instead  $complete = preg_replace('/^(.*?):/', "<font color=red>$1</font>:", $line);

Comment: for some reason, this colors the end. name: <color>text</color>

Comment: You can use preg_replace no problem with the right regex.  However, the preg_ functions while very powerful, are going to be a lot slower than explode or substr_replace.  This is why I did not mention them.