# PHP: Replace all instances

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

I have a chatlog file that looks like this (name represents screenames and text is their chat string)

```
name: some text
name2: more text
name: text
name3: text
```

I want to color all names up to the `:` red. 
For example: `<font color=red>myname:</fontcolor> hello`
How would I do this?

I'm not sure why, but this code colors everything *after* the colon

```
echo preg_replace('/(.*?):/', "<font color=#F00>$1</font>:", $output);
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me:
$ php
<?php
$output=<<<EOF
james: hello
paul: how are you?
simon: i'm good
EOF;
echo preg_replace('/(.*?):/', "<font color=#F00>$1</font>:", $output);
?>
<font color=#F00>james</font>: hello
<font color=#F00>paul</font>: how are you?
<font color=#F00>simon</font>: i'm good

Comment: Stupid me, Jonathan is right. I just tried your code and it works fine.

Comment: @Jonathan It doesn't work for me. http://pastebin.com/0Ym1Njdz is my full code. I should also note that this chatlog is updated every .5 seconds via ajax

Comment: @hosh http://209.141.56.244/test/query.html is where I'm running the code and only the first line is colored

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A correct answer to this question has been provided previously:

Look at the second answer:

[PHP: insert text up to delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296751/php-insert-text-up-to-delimiter/7296820#7296820)

In addition, your implementation is wrong, look at the regular expression it should start with ^ :

```
echo preg_replace('/(.*?):/', "<font color=#F00>$1</font>:", $output);
```

Should be:

```
echo preg_replace('/^(.*?):/', "<font color=#F00>$1</font>:", $output);
```

Comment: putting the carrot makes it only color the first line of the file. While removing the carrot makes it color all the text _after_ the colon

Comment: Yes Kevin, I'm assuming you are reading the content of the file into a string. This will only match the very first name: < you have in that file! Hence in order to match all, you should parse the file into an array, then loop through each line and replace the first of each with the new html (that colors to red).

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if my file is a string or not. `$output = shell_exec('exec tail -n50 ' . $filename);` is how I get $output

Comment: If you are curious, I am running your code right now here: http://209.141.56.244/test/query.html and as you can see, only the first line is colored

Comment: It is a string, it is clear since the regex only replaces the first only. If you use "echo $output" you should be able to echo it without errors, for if it was an array you would have an fatal error.

Comment: Could you try the following: [http://pastebin.com/23P4WTv6](http://pastebin.com/23P4WTv6)

Comment: Sorry left a bug in the previous comment try this one please:[http://pastebin.com/1WapuCEk](http://pastebin.com/1WapuCEk)

Comment: hm I get a invalid argument supplied for foreach

Comment: my bad again. replace `foreach($str as $line)` with `foreach($output as $line)`

Comment: `Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Empty regular expression in /var/www/test/logtee.php on line 13`

Comment: your code is here: http://pastebin.com/ZzVSQpg7 however error seems same: http://209.141.56.244/test/query.html

Comment: It's very hard to debug this way :) nevertheless, try this last mod [http://pastebin.com/9kzcse3Z](http://pastebin.com/9kzcse3Z)

Comment: I get really weird output, all n characters are replaced with `:`, see url

Comment: Good, now replace  `$pattern = "/^[a-z0-9]+:?/";` with `$pattern = "/^(.*?):/"`

Comment: replace `$output = split('\n', $output);` with `$output = explode("\n", $output);`

Comment: running your code (http://pastebin.com/4P1jBXSN) it only affects the first line again, confirm with the url

Comment: I'm sorry, I give up :) I've tried everything to make this work, the original question was straightforward and the provided answers should have worked perfectly, but this is getting out of my league for I'm not able to test on the fly.

Comment: You are most welcome Kevin :) Sorry I couldn't be of further help.

Comment: no problem, awesome people like you make stack overflow amazing :)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
echo preg_replace('/^(.*?):(.*?)$/s', "<font color=#F00>\\1</font>:\\2", $output);
```

EDIT:
This should work (tried it):

```
trim(preg_replace("/(?:\n)(.*?):(.*?)/s", "<font color=#F00>\\1</font>:\\2", "\n".$str))
```

Final try, maybe try to explode it instead:

```
<?php
$content = 'name: some text
name2: more text
name: text
name3: text';
$tmp = explode("\n", $content);
for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp); $i ++) {
    $tmp[$i] = '<span style="color:#F00">'.str_replace(':', '</span>:', $tmp[$i], 1);
}
echo implode("\n", $tmp);
?>
```

This does assume that whatever is before the colon, it won't have another colon.

---

My bad, I misunderstood str_replace()'s last parameter. Try this:

```
<?php
$tmp = explode("\n", $content);
for($i = 0; $i < count($tmp); $i ++) {
    $tmp2 = explode(':', $tmp[$i]);
    $tmp2[0] = '<span style="color:#F00">'.$tmp2[0].'</span>';
    $tmp[$i] = implode(':', $tmp2);
}
echo implode("\n", $tmp);
```

Comment: ugh, still only works for first line of file. I think maybe the problem is not your code but rather something else on my side

Comment: `Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in /var/www/test/logtee.php on line `

Comment: You must have other code before what I put, can you open up the file and copy and paste line 6 here?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/941raNnp line 10. sort of a hack and slash without me thinking

Comment: Try the last one, I misunderstood str_replace()'s last parameter.

Comment: what do you mean by try the last one?

Answer (score 0):

put the : inside the font tag after $1

```
echo preg_replace('/^(.*?):/', "<font color=#F00>$1:</font>", $output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z0-9]*):/', "<font color=#F00>$1</font>:", $output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the regex more specific:

```
= preg_replace('/^(\w+):/m', ...
```

Or if usernames can contain non-alphanum symbols:

```
= preg_replace('/^(\S+):/m', "<b>$1</b>:", $output);
```